# Entity Framework not adding multiple objects

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Im trying to add some dummy content into my database. I have a sample object called "obj", and I'm using a for loop to insert data like the code below:

```
  public async Task<Post> Add(Post obj)
        {
            if (db != null)
            {
                obj.Id = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    await db.Post.AddAsync(obj);
                }
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();

                return obj;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

However, it does add only 1 record into database, could you please explain what's wrong here?

Comment: You're telling EF a hundred times that `obj` should be inserted (while one time tends to be enough for the poor thing). Instead *different instances* should be inserted, so you have to create them in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Can you create object of post inside the loop and try again?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)                
{
   Post obj = new Post();
   await db.Post.AddAsync(obj);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your replying, I tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the below commands before calling saved changes you can see what changes EF Core has queued up.

```
        var post = new Post();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            
            await db.Posts.AddAsync(dev);
        }

        db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        Debug.WriteLine(db.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This will write to Debug that one post is currently being tracked.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var post = new Post();
            await db.Posts.AddAsync(dev);
        }

        db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        Debug.WriteLine(db.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This will right to the Debug window the 10 posts are currently being tracked.

In your code when you AddAsync(obj), obj isn't a new object and EF Core is already tracking obj.

Moving Post obj = new Post() into the loop creates a new object for EF Core to track. If these objects aren't being added to the DB my guess would be that they don't meet a requirement for the Post model.

Either way playing around with

```
db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

Debug.WriteLine(db.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
```

should help you be able to track down exactly what's going on.

I do hope you find this information helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1?view=efcore-5.0).

```
public async Task<Post> Add(Post obj)
        {
            if (db != null)
            {
               List<Post>=new List<Post>();
                obj.Id = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    l.Add(obj);
                }
                await db.Post.AddRangeAsync(l);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();

                return obj;
            }
            return null;
        }
```